# Unable to add "Site" as an entity in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Unable to add an entity with Site as its name.The application does start but the index page doesn't load at all.
Does anyone faced such issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal because the root state of a JHipster app is named 'site' which conflicts with the state to manage your 'site' entity.

Solution is to rename JHipster root state defined in app.js to something else like 'root' and then update all its child states by searching for `parent: 'site'` and replacing it by `parent: 'root'`.